# Android, Intellij slidemenu without actionbar

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I create a project with actionbarsherlock and slidingmenu library, i want to remove actionbarsherlock from my project, I don't wonna use it, so I went to project properties and then remove library of actionbar sherlock, now this is the error when i'm trying to build my project:

> java: error: error reading
>   C:\Users\Omid.IdeaIC12\system\compile-server\kiwi
>   store_4e535ca1\targets\java-production\SlideMenu\android\generated_sources\build_config\com\actionbarsherlock\BuildConfig.java;
>   C:\Users\Omid.IdeaIC12\system\compile-server\kiwi
>   store_4e535ca1\targets\java-production\SlideMenu\android\generated_sources\build_config\com\actionbarsherlock\BuildConfig.java
>   (The system cannot find the path specified)

and this is the class:

```
package ir.mykiwi.store.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import ir.mykiwi.store.Main;
import ir.mykiwi.store.R;

public class BirdGridFragment extends Fragment {

    private int mPos = -1;

    public BirdGridFragment() { }
    public BirdGridFragment(int pos) {
        mPos = pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (mPos == -1 && savedInstanceState != null)
            mPos = savedInstanceState.getInt("mPos");

        GridView gv = (GridView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_grid, null);
        gv.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.black);
        gv.setAdapter(new GridAdapter());
        gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                if (getActivity() == null)
                    return;
                Main activity = (Main) getActivity();
                activity.myClick(mPos);
            }           
        });
        return gv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("mPos", mPos);
    }

    private class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
            }
            return convertView;
        }

    }
}
```

Intellij shows error here : `Main activity = (Main) getActivity();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know slidingmenu doesn't have any dependency on SherlockActionbar.
Also if you like intellij i suggest you try out Android Studio, from google.It basically Intellij with benefits.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: I mean ABS folder in slidingmenu , i've remove that library and now it giving me this error : `java: G:\Suite Projects\Kiwi Market\MobileApp\IntelliJ-Idea\SlidingMenu\library\src\com\slidingmenu\lib\app\SlidingMapActivity.java:8: package com.google.android.maps does not exist`

Comment: there is many error like this on my project, i have to remove it because of apk size, it's so heavy for my project. and I don't need it

Comment: I don't want to use android studio, I have it and I know this the IDE of android studio came from jetBrains. but for some reasons i have to use intelliJ